# How to transfer specific cells of information from a number of spreadsheets to one summary spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am wondering how I can take specific cells from a number of Excel Spreadsheets and put it into one master spreadsheet. On these individual spreadsheets, in some of the rows of data it has 'yes' in it or just 'blank'. These yes or blank values are also connected to number values ($2,089.00, etc.) and these values are what I want to be copied into a master file. I want to copy all of the number values that are ONLY connected to the cells that have 'yes' in it.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can start a Query from an Excel table. If you spreadsheets are in separate files it has a great function to import all the files in a Windows Folder in a single step and append all their data together (assuming the file columns are consistent).  If they are multiple sheets in a single file then you will need multiple Queries, which you can combine together using the Append command.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/append-queries-HA104149760.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA103993872

Then I would use the Filter command to only keep the rows with 'Yes'.  Then I would deliver the result to a new Excel Table.